# Make a row in color with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to display a row in red on the index page if the model has :updated = true. How can i do that using activeadmin?

Thx

Comment: Even though this does not update the entire row, but might be in handy as an alternative update https://salayhin.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/add-custom-style-for-active-admin-boolean-fileds/

Answer (score 17):

As of Active Admin 1.0.0pre1, it is possible to specify row class based on the properties of the record in that row. To assign a class to rows with updated records, you can write the following, supposing you have some update check function `was_updated?`:

**app/admin/my_model.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do

    ...

    index(:row_class => -> record { 'my-class' if record.was_updated? }) do

      # whatever columns you want:
      # selectable_column
      # id_column
      # column :attribute
      # actions
    end

    ...

end
```

This new option is commented on in the source code for [indexing as a table.](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/9c46b14ea0d9b3aaaa3d7520555c9959d06ce7f3/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb)

However, Active Admin's SCSS uses a lot of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) when it dictates table row (or rather, table data) colors, making them impossible to override with custom colors by just writing `.my-class { background-color: red; }` in your stylesheet. I found the following to work, though:

**app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss**

```
...

tr.odd, tr.even {
    &.my-class {
        td.col {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `background-color: red !important;` should work without having to over-specify the selector.

Answer (score 3):

Table rendering for Active Admin is hardcored in `ActiveAdmin::Views::TableFor` as follows:

```
  def build_table_body
    @tbody = tbody do
      # Build enough rows for our collection
      @collection.each{|_| tr(:class => cycle('odd', 'even'), :id => dom_id(_)) }
    end
  end
```

So probably the easiest way is to monkeypatch that method. I don't see if subclassing can help.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want something that is quick, and dispense of the need for monkeypatching Activeadmin, can't you just stick divs inside your table?  Like f ex

```
table_for invoice.ccpayment do
  column 'Payments and payments attempts on this invoice: ' do |p|
    if p.paymentcomplete > 0
      div :class => 'green' do
        'Payment # '+p.id.to_s+' of '+p.currency.iso+' '+p.amount.to_s+' on '+p.created_at.to_s
      end
    else
      div :class => 'red' do
        'FAILED Payment # '+p.id.to_s+' of '+p.currency.iso+' '+p.amount.to_s+' on '+p.created_at.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can easily define those classes in 'activeadmin.css.scss'

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to do that and the easiest way I found was using JavaScript
Of course this is not a good solution because I'm relaying on tags\classes\ids and ActiveAdmin rendering can be completely changed on the next version...
But if you will add a couple of test cases it might be good enough

For example, I wanted to color each row by its rating column

So I put this code in file : **A.js** (under app\assets\javascripts of course)

```
// A.js

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('td.rating').each(function(i,obj) {
        var rating = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
        if (!isNaN(rating))
        {
            var rowcolor = ""
            if (rating<5)
            {
                rowcolor = "#FF0000"; //red
            }
            else
            {
                var red = Math.round(255-(rating-5)*51);
                var green = 255; 
                rowcolor = "#"+decimalToHex(red,2)+decimalToHex(green)+"00";
            }
            obj.parentElement.className = "";               
            obj.parentElement.setAttribute('style', '');
            obj.parentElement.style.background = rowcolor;
        }
    });

});

function decimalToHex(d, padding) {
    var hex = Number(d).toString(16);
    padding = typeof (padding) === "undefined" || padding === null ? padding = 2 : padding;

    while (hex.length < padding) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }

    return hex;
};
```

**and in my ActiveAdmin model**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Bla do

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :rating
    <my other columns>
    default_actions
    script :src => javascript_path('A.js'), :type => "text/javascript"
  end
end
```

So, after the index is being rendered , my JS function go over and colors all the rows according to the rating column value (red for 0..4 - yellow..green for 5..10)

[image: Example of coloring ActiveAdmin rows]

Hope this could help